# Getting null value by using session.getAttribute("firstname")

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I got null value into jsp textbox. Please tell me where I am wrong.

**index.jsp**

```html
<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td><input type="text" required="" name="firstname" value="<%=session.getAttribute("firstname")%>"/></td>
</tr>
```

**UploadServletClass.java**

```html
String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
...
session.setAttribute("firstname", firstname);
```

Comment: Please do not use scriptlets... read about JSTL. Could you also use a form to send this to your servlet?

Comment: @rhenesys please check above code now

Comment: please help me with this